# Identity MySQL EF Pomelo Core 2.2 - Two user tables to one UserId FK relationship not displaying user results

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have three MySQL tables that all appear to have been generated correctly with .Net Core 2.2. code first with Pomelo/EF framework:

- AspnetUsers with PK=UserId (default Identity Users table with Id
  changed to UserId)
- UserSetting with PK=UserId

I originally had these as one User table on my last project and wanted to leave Identity alone as much as possible and so I created a second table to hold other user settings.

The problem exists on my third table called Incident with this FK relationship currently:

```
public class Incident
    {
        [Key]
        public int IncidentId { get; set; }
        ...
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        ...
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserSetting UserSetting { get; set; }
}
```

So, ideally I'll be able to pull values from both the AspnetUsers table and the UserSetting table to form one complete user. However, when trying to do this:

```
IQueryable<Incident> incident = _context.Incident.OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
```

And then get at either:

```
incident.User (e.g. incident.User.Username)
incident.UserSetting (e.g. incident.UserSetting.IPAddress)
```

I get a `NullReferenceException`. I think EF is confused or maybe I am... but when I remove the annotations and let EF try to sort it out, I get this error message when running add-migration:

> Both relationships between 'Incident.User' and 'IdentityUser' and
>   between 'Incident.UserSetting' and 'UserSetting' could use {'UserId'}
>   as the foreign key. To resolve this configure the foreign key
>   properties explicitly on at least one of the relationships

I tried several things and none the wiser. I've definitely checked that the UserId value matches in all three tables (so it's not null because it's actually null). When I look in the debugger output I don't see any joins being done on the select statement.

I thought about creating a FK relationship between UserSetting and the AspnetUsers table (e.g. `incident.User.Usersetting.IPAddress`), but again, trying to get away from the tweaking of Identity which appears to be mostly invisible without scaffolding it.

How do I link both my user tables to my Incident table using one UserId property in that Incident table? Is this maybe a bad idea (i.e. should I just go back to using a single user table)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake... I was converting a four year old project from .NET Framework to .NET Core. .NET Framework doesn't require the `.Include()` statements. So, I simply changed:

```
IQueryable<Incident> incident = _context.Incident.OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
```

To:

```
var incident = _context.Incident
                .Include(u => u.User)
                .Include(u => u.UserSetting)
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
```